# USBStick unreadble, gparted cannot (re)format, says: stick is readonly

Tags: usb, gparted, write-protect

I have a USB-stick (Intenso, 4GB), used to recording at TV.
One day I transferred some music-directories to it (using windows 7), and played it at my panasonic music system.
After that, I observed difficulties with the directory structure under Win7. Tried to repair, didn't work properly, tried to format - suddenly Win7-diskmanager says: device is empty, unknown bootsector, could not re-format. Next try: Win7-"Diskpart" says: "disk is readonly, 0 Byte on disk"

Loooked at it under Ubuntu 22, gparted says: device empty, cannot format, device is readonly.

Hmmm. The stick does not have some obvious switch for read/write-modus, and trying this and that I could not repair the stick with any tool I have.

> Q: Is there -perhaps- another lowlevel- functionality which is able to switch between the readonly/write-modus?

*<sub>Remark: this attempt-of-repair of a 4GB-stick might be oversized; but I would like to learn how this could happen and learn about possible tricks/software (example: in old DOS-time the Norton-Diskeditor has been a useful tool, and I've learnt a lot with its help) that are perhaps common knowledge</sub>*